# trigger alert after jquery isotope filter completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I have jquery isotope setup and have created some filters. When i create I select a filter, isotope does a nice little animation. I want to trigger an alert at the end of the animation.

This example demostrates the animation that occurs:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html

Any ideas?

Here is the code for the on click of a filter:

```
$('.filter').on( 'click', 'a', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
            return false;
        }

        // console.log('hello world');
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
        var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
        options.comboFilters[ group ] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
        $.bbq.pushState( options );

        // COUNT
        var $filtered = $('#isotope-container').data('isotope').$filteredAtoms;
        // get count of all filtered item
        alert($filtered.length);
        // get count of all filtered items that match a selector
        //$filtered.filter('.blue').length;
  });
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433862/callback-for-jquery-plugin-isotope

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since v1.5 ([changelog](https://github.com/desandro/isotope#changelog)), Isotope provides a callback to do just that; it is described in [Isotope's Introduction](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html) (just search the page for `callback`):

> Additionally you can specify a callback after the options object. This function will be triggered after the animation has completed.

```
onAnimationFinished = function(){
  // code to be executed after the animation finishes
};

$('#container').isotope({ filter: '.my-selector' }, onAnimationFinished);
```

For live examples take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5qFq/) which throws an alert when changing a filter via the checkbox inputs or peep [Isotope's Callback Test](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/tests/callbacks.html) source and search for `changeBGColor`.

Answer (score 5):

None of them worked for me. Instead, I used what is explained in event sections :
 http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html

```
function onLayout() {
        // What to do when layout fully rendered
    }
    // bind event listener
    $isotope.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete', onLayout );
```

Answer (score 3):

This didn't work for me using Isotope 2.0. I'm also not using jQuery so perhaps the usage is different with vanilla JS.

Either way, if anyone runs into this problme, I got it to work using 2.0's event callback: `iso.on('layoutComplete', myFunction)`.

More info on Isotope events: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me. I'm not sure if it's the latest version of Isotope, and/or jQuery 2.1.1. Regardless, I found a solution on [github](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/732):

$isotope.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", myFunction);